# Como organizar uma tabela MySQL de forma eficiente e escalável?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, refatoração

Estou fazendo uma refatoração em um sistem que possui diversas com muitas tabelas que possuem muitas colunas, isto é, chega até 148 colunas em uma tabela, como refatorar tal tabela?

Essa é a tabela

```
CREATE TABLE `periodizacao12` (
  `periodizacao_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `weeks` int(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '12',
  `startDate` date NOT NULL,
  `mesocicloNome1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mesocicloNome2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mesocicloNome3` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mesocicloNome4` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mesocicloNome5` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mesocicloNome6` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mesocicloNome7` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mesocicloNome8` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mesocicloNome9` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mesocicloNome10` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mesocicloNome11` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mesocicloNome12` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo1_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo1_es` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo2_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo2_es` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo3` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo3_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo3_es` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo4` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo4_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo4_es` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo5` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo5_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo5_es` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo6` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo6_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo6_es` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo7` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo7_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo7_es` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo8` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo8_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo8_es` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo9` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo9_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo9_es` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo10` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo10_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo10_es` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo11` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo11_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo11_es` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo12` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo12_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_objetivo1s_es` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_treino1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_treino2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_treino3` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_treino4` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_treino5` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_treino6` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_treino7` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_treino8` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_treino9` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_treino10` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_treino11` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `periodizacao_treino12` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino3` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino4` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino5` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino6` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino7` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino8` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino9` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino10` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino11` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino12` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino13` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino14` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino15` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino16` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino17` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino18` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino19` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino20` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino21` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino22` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino23` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino24` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino25` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino26` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino27` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino28` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino29` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino30` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino31` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino32` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino33` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino34` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino35` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino36` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino37` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino38` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino39` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino40` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino41` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino42` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino43` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino44` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino45` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino46` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino47` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino48` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino49` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino50` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino51` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino52` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino53` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino54` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino55` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino56` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino57` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino58` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino59` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino60` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino61` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino62` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino63` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino64` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino65` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino66` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino67` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino68` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino69` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino70` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino71` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino72` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino73` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino74` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino75` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino76` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino77` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino78` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino79` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino80` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino81` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino82` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino83` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `listOfTreino84` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

A tabela é para uma lista de treinos de um usuário numa academia.

Comment: O que tem nos campos listOfTreino, periodizacao_treino etc...?

Comment: @Peter tem variações de treinos como A, B ,C ...

Comment: A criação ou modificação de uma base de dados, depende muito do que vc quer fazer. Se vc quer "ajuda", vc deve descrever o que tem nos campos, porque este tipo de dados, como os campos são usados etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem conheçer as intenções por detrás do código ou a forma como esta tabela se relaciona com as demais tabelas é dificil dar opiniões mas algo que me salta à vista são as multiplas colunas com o nome idêntico (a diferença é o Indice) - `listOfTreino`.

Estas colunas parecem-me fortes candidatas a serem colocadas numa tabela separada que se relaciona com a tabela do utilizador através do id do utilizador. Esta tabela em vez de terem 84 colunas tem apenas 3 (`user_id`, `treino_id`, `value`), ficando assim na versão "transposta" das colunas originais. O campo `user_id` é a chave para o utilizador, o `treino_id` é o numero que replica as 84 colunas originais e o campo `valor` registará o valor tal como inserido na tabela original.

```
CREATE TABLE `listOfTreinos` (
  `user_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `treino_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(100) NOT NULL
```

O mesmo raciocionio pode ser aplicado aos restantes campos, uma vez que parecem ser todos relacionados (partilham o mesmo nomes diferindo do indice de 1 a 12). Assim podem ser re-estruturados para uma tabela com os seguintes campos:

```
CREATE TABLE `listOfTreinos` (
 `user_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
 `mesocicloId` int(50) NOT NULL,
 `mesocicloNome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `periodizacao_objetivo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `periodizacao_objetivo_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `periodizacao_objetivo_es` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `periodizacao_treino` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Mas como disse antes, isto depende do que se pretende fazer e da forma como se quer fazer.